# Random errors when using xarray on netCDF files

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf

I'm using xarray to extract data from various netcdf files to analyses and plot different meteorological data. This is an example of a script I'm using for this.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.measure import block_reduce

data = xr.open_mfdataset("filepath\*.nc", parallel=True)

tas = np.array(data['tas'])
time = np.array(data['time'])

x = np.array(data['projection_x_coordinate'])
y = np.array(data['projection_y_coordinate'])

lat = np.array(data['latitude'])
lon = np.array(data['longitude'])

temp = block_reduce(tas, block_size=(12,1,1), func=np.mean, cval=np.mean(tas))

time = np.arange(1884,2023)


plt.plot(time, temp[:, 23, 62], 'r', label='London')
plt.plot(time, temp[:, 22, 55], 'c', label='Headley')
plt.plot(time, temp[:, 23, 59], 'g', label='Egham')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time (1884-2022)')
plt.ylabel('Temperature [C]')
plt.title('Heat Island Effect for Average Monthly Temperature')
```

My issue is is that the code seems to work and not work randomly. Sometimes I get the expected output and sometimes I get errors such as:

```
OSError: [Errno -51] NetCDF: Unknown file format: b'C:filepath\\tas_hadukgrid_uk_12km_mon_197201-197212.nc'

RuntimeError: NetCDF: Not a valid ID

KeyError: [<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>, ('C:filepath\\tas_hadukgrid_uk_12km_mon_197401-197412.nc',), 'r', (('clobber', True), ('diskless', False), ('format', 'NETCDF4'), ('persist', False)), '621f2ad1-8dca-4c52-83d3-1f7fe6b4972d']
```

I also get warning such as:

```
C:\Users\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py:219: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
  "class": algorithms.Blowfish,
```

And the kernel restarts.

I'm using spyder as an IDE but the problems persist in Jupyter and VScode. I have uninstalled and reinstalled all my packages multiple times as well as miniconda. I have also factory reset my laptop to make sure there were no conda files interfering with fresh installs but nothing seems to work.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to be totally sure what is going on with the first error without access to the file. Either the file is corrupt or something or there is a problem with your xarray/dependencies installation. The second is just a warning message to say that something is deprecated, i.e. it works now but will fail in future. Just ignore that: it's someone else's job to fix it

Comment: Thanks for you comment! I have other scripts that use the different netcdf files and I get the same errors.

Comment: As I said, the error message is reasonably clear. xarray does not like the data. Either the file is bad, something is wrong with your installations, or xarray is just not able to handle it. There is no way for us to figure out why without access to the file itself.

Comment: +1 ; I am running into the same problem. The issue disappears on my end if I set open_mfdataset(parallel=False). I have not yet been able reliable reproduce the issue, because as OP says it occurs sporadically.